# How to catch all the exceptions but someone in python?

Tags: python, exception

I want to catch all the exceptions but someone, `e.g. KeyboardInterrupt,`

the following is part of my code:

```
try:
    num = 70
    while 1:
        print 'hello %d' % num
        sleep(0.1)
        num += 1
        a = 1/(num - 80)
except not KeyboardInterrupt:
        print 'ctrl c'
        save(num)
```

It does not work.

Comment: Why? What do you want to do when someone presses Ctrl-C?

Comment: it's just an example for my question, I want to save something when ctrl+c pressed in my another program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch and re-raise it before the general case

```
try:
    #stuff
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    raise #rethrow to a higher handler
except:
    #everything else
```

Comment: Yikes, that's mean ;). He didn't say he wants to ignore it, he wanted not to catch it...

Comment: Good solution now. Still bad practice to do so, but answers the question.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, ignoring exceptions you expect!? Yeah, pretty bad :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy with also not catching `SystemExit` and `StopIteration`, just do

```
except Exception:
```

because that only catches "higher-level" exceptions. Still, this is considered bad practice. Always be specific in catching exceptions.

Comment: to remember or learn the specific exceptions is a problem for me

Comment: Sorry, but if learning is a problem for you, why are you trying to program a computer?

Comment: i just don't want to learn exceptions right now, maybe when i realize the importance of exceptions, i will learn it.